# get jquery element from other view template in emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have an Emberjs application with jQuery, and i met strange thing, but maybe it's a feature :).

I have a main view template, let's name it **main.hbs**.

And this template has child template child1.hbs: {{outlet child1}}

I know that every template has it's own .js file (main.js and child1.js)

In child1.js I have a code like this:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
      console.log(Ember.$('.somediv-from-main-hbs').length);
   }
});
```

I need to get element from parent view, but I can't. 
Is there any way to access to the element from parent template?

Thank you.

Comment: I think it should work! this$('selector') woulnt work, but Ember.$ should be the global jQuery! Can you provide a sample on http://emberjs.jsbin.com or so?

Comment: It doesn't work. I put jQuery selector and it did not find element
console.log(Ember.$('.chat-header').height()); // equals 0, it means no element found, but in parent js file the same code console.log(Ember.$('.chat-header').height()); // equals 1, element found. But I need element to be found in child .js file.

Comment: Well, please provide a sample and we will be able to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a change, that your view is yet rendered?

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
      this._super();

      console.log($('.somediv-from-main-hbs').length);
   }
});
```

Or even

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
   didInsertElement: function() {
      this._super();

      Ember.run.next(function () {
          console.log($('.somediv-from-main-hbs').length);
      });
   }
});
```